# when pymysql using local_infile, data is not insert database

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

I created the code to create and execute SQL query statements using pymysql in Python.

If i put the sql query statement generated in code directly in db, it works normally.

However, if i execute the sql query statement created in code with cursor.execute (sql), db will not contain data.

When I connect, I also gave the local_infile = True option. How do I create the code?

Comment: code? error message? what are you hoping to achieve? are you sure you've set up pymysql correctly, or is this your first time using it?

Comment: sorry to small information but i think it is simple question. i resolve this problem, i forget 'commit' so i write conn.commit()